# SolrCloud: Why solr core send data to another shard leader

Tags: solr

I catch this line in solr.log:

```
2017-12-07 09:46:17.737 INFO  (qtp834133664-19646) [c:test_collection s:s9 r:core_node27 x:test_collection_s9_replica3] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [test_collection_s9_replica3]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http://server:port/solr/test_collection_s2_replica2/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[15046286453 (1586091553171963909), 15046286489 (1586091553171963910), 15046286730 (1586091553171963913), 15046286739 (1586091553171963915), 15046286763 (1586091553171963918), 15046286770 (1586091553173012481), 15046286771 (1586091553173012482), 15046286773 (1586091553173012484), 15046287190 (1586091553173012486), 15046287195 (1586091553173012487), ... (52 adds)]} 0 8
```

It looks like shard9 (s9) is sending data to leader of shard2 (s2).
Why is it happen? I think a document belong to one and only one shard.

Edit: there's no updateProcessor defined, and document routing is implicit.

Comment: This is probably due to document id routing. We can be sure if you provide more details of your solr configuration and especially the updatProcessorChain used

Comment: Edited. There's no updateProcessor defined, and document routing is implicit. 
Also this log occurs in recovery state, so I think it might not be document routing.